# Posts query according to meta box date

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, metabox, query-posts, get-posts

I'm struggling to get a working solution with wp_query for Event management, Currently post order by event start date & time work well. Now I want some custom settings.

> Have two meta boxes working with `meta_key=> start_datetime` and `meta_key=> end_datetime`

**1-** `key=> end_datetime` is a date and time for the post to end (no longer display in the results)

**2-** Additionally print some text in posts as two hours remain to start event. `e.g <p>LIVE</p>`

**How to hide post when date&time end, and add some text as remain 2 hours to start?**

```
$today = date("Y/m/j");
$args (array(
  'post_type' => 'event',
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
  'meta_key' => 'start_datetime',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'start_datetime',
      'value' => $today,
      'compare' => '>=',
      'type' => 'CHAR'
    )
   ),
  'tax_query' => array(
  'relation' => 'AND',
  array(
    'key' => 'end_datetime',
    'meta-value' => $value,
    'compare' => '=<'
  )
 )
));
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  while( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    the_title();
  }
}
```

Comment: You've lost [`relation`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) in the query.

Comment: Relation is default set to AND so it doesn't need to be set, see [WP docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Initializing_WP_Meta_Query).

Answer (score 1):

I checked your query and there's a lot of junk in there. You define meta keys 2x. Once as meta_key and once as meta_query. Only keep the query, it has more options.

Second, the tax query is all wrong. The parameters for a tax query are not the same as a meta query. You need taxonomy, field, terms and possible compare. I don't see a reason to use a tax query, based on your info, so I removed it in my example.

I am a fan of storing dates/times as a unix timestamp. Is a lot easier to compare and order than a date string. By looking at your today string, I assume the rest is in that format as well, so I will use that for the example.

I wrote the code below by heart since I had no events to work with (with that meta key), but I think you'll get most of the desired result and if not, maybe tweak it a little.

```
$today = date( 'Y/m/d' );

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        // get posts which have an end_datetime which is bigger than or equal to $today (and thus hide the ones which have ended before today)
        'end_clause' => array(
            'key'     => 'end_datetime',
            'value'   => $today,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type'    => 'DATE'
        )
    ),
    'orderby'        => array( 'end_clause' => 'DESC' ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();

        the_title();

        // check if start_datetime is not empty
        if ( ! empty( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'start_datetime', 1 ) ) ) {
            // make unix timestamp of start_datetime
            $start_datetime = strtotime( date( 'U', get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'start_datetime', 1 ) ) );
            // make unix timestamp of now
            $now            = date( 'U', current_time( 'timestamp' ) );
            // if (start_time - now) is smaller than 7200 seconds
            if ( ( $start_datetime - $now ) < 2 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS ) {
                echo '<p>LIVE</p>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Sorry for late. After copy & past its not show anything, I change `type=>CHAR` then this code give output which have issues. 1- Query print Live in each post. 2- `(no longer display in the results` also not work.

Comment: The 'type' DATE works with the 'compare' value BETWEEN only. see here [codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query)

Comment: Oh snap, @FRQ6692 you're right, forgot that.

Comment: After a little bit modification this code work. The only thing remain to adjust is `not to display posts when time end` please take a look. Thanks

Comment: I think you need to change `$start_datetime - $now` to `$end_datetime - now` (my error).

Comment: No,,, Editing required in `meta_query` see also your comment there. because we get only that post which `bigger than or equal to $today`